Is the unit of a monoid object in an $\infty$-category unique?
Suppose one has a non-unital monoid object $M$ in some cartesian monoidal $\infty$-category, in the sense that one has a map $M^n \to M^m$ for every injective map $\iota : [m] \hookrightarrow [n]$ in the simplex category, rather than for every map $[m] \to [n]$ in the simplex category.
Is it necessarily the case that the space of units, defined as the space of completions of the data of $M$ to the data of a unital monoid object, is necessarily either empty or contractible by dint of there being a canonical path between any two units?
An auxiliary question is whether giving the data of a left unit and right unit, specified by giving an element and a sequence of simplex-shaped homotopies giving the degenerate simplices where either the last two or first two vertices coincide, gives the data of a unit by the conventional definition.

Generally any unit will induce an equivalence $A \otimes I \simeq A$ which means for two units we have $I_1 \simeq I_1 \otimes I_2 \simeq I_2$, so it will always be unique up to equivalence.

The problem is that I need an equivalence of all the higher data as well.

This is answered (affirmatively) in Lurie's Higher Algebra, in a section about nonunital algebras

Thank you, this resolves the main question
